# How does tankage mass really scale?

Tags: propulsion, tanks, mass-fraction

A problem that frequently shows up is estimating the mass of the propellant tanks of some hypothetical rocket configuration. This need arises from the important role of the dry mass in [a rather famous equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

Two assumptions that are often made:

1. Tankage mass is proportional to propellant mass. ("the mass fraction is scale independent")
2. Tankage mass and propellant mass have a [square-cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law) relationship.

The actual values obviously differ both by propellant type, and by rocket configuration (launch vs. deep space). But the problem is still:

**How well do the two assumptions above compare to real-world data?**

And if those don't fit well at all, what better heuristic can be made?

Comment: Doesn't propellant volume play a role also? The development of cryogenics was essential to the success of the Saturn program, as [using gaseous propellants would have made the tankage impossibly big](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch4.htm)

Comment: @Ludo Implied by "propellant type". Gaseous oxygen is something else than liquid oxygen.

Comment: I would predict a square/cube relationship if tanks were *spherical*. Once your tank stops being spherical, you can only increase the propellant mass by making the tank *longer*. Thus, each marginal increase to propellant is effectively a disc of propellant surrounded by a ring of tank, which is a constant ratio no matter how long the tank grows.

Comment: RO/RP-1 dev team, is that you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NASA TM-78661 [TECHNIOUES
FOR THE DETERMINATION
OF MASS
PROPERTIES
OF EARTH-TO-ORBIT
TRANSPORTATION SYSTEMS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19780022221/downloads/19780022221.pdf) agrees with the "proportional" method

> Main propulsion system tank mass, if non integral, is much more
> sensitive to vehicle physical size and varies as L<sub>r</sub><sup>3</sup> or **directly as
> propellant mass** since tank mass is approximately equal to a constant
> times propellant volume for any given shape.

(L<sub>r</sub> is the vehicle reference length, emphasis mine)

This slide from [Mass Estimating Relations](https://spacecraft.ssl.umd.edu/academics/791S16/791S16L08.MERsx.pdf) shows linear fits that appear to be based on real world examples of tanks (the points on the graph), although frustratingly they don't say *what* tanks were used in the analysis. They derive slopes of 9.09 kg/m³ for hydrogen and 12.16 kg/m³ for other propellants. (It also references TM-78661)

[image]

Comment: Nice! They even offer two concrete such values: 9.09 kg/m³ (hydrogen), 12.16 kg/m³ (other propellants)

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys yes, that presentation looks pretty helpful.  Some of the other references might be useful as well.

Comment: Reading further, the presentation still goes into square-cube territory with insulation for cryogenic propellants (2.88 kg/m² for LH2, 1.123 kg/m² for LOX)

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys that's for the mass *of the insulation*, no? Which makes sense because it would be applied to the surface.

Comment: [This 2009 study](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/382034main_018%20-%2020090706.05.Analysis_of_Propellant_Tank_Masses.pdf) uses "empty mass less engines" rather than "tank mass", so will include insulation as well as structural mass, equipment, etc, but does have details on a stage-by-stage basis.

Comment: @Andrew thanks! It's great how that one labels the data points.

Comment: Andrew's link uses a scaling by propellant^0.85, which is between the propellant^1 scaling of constant ratio and propellant^0.67 by square-cube.

Comment: @Andrew that might be worth writing a separate answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble please do feel free to incorporate it here, my brain fuzzed a bit trying to get my head around the numbers so I'm not sure I'd do it justice :-)